# Fetch ManytoOne based on certain condition

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using `Hibernate 3.5.4` version as Orm I have two tables which have many to one relationship , Like Table 'Book' can have many 'Authors' associated with It.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "key.bookId", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)   
public Set<BookAuthor> getAuthors() {
    return authors;
}
```

But we use soft delete for deleting the association (we maintain a column named `isDeleted`) , i want to fetch the entity based on `isDeleted` check if its 1 it should not be loaded , else if 0 load it.

Is it possible by modifying this current fetching strategy to provide above support or there is another better solution that can be applied please let me know.

Comment: This article should sum the scenario you need: https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-where-clause

Comment: I would be very careful about using Where at class level. As far as I know you can't override the Where-Clause if it is annotated at class level. Declaring Where or Filter with the getter is more flexible.

Comment: Strongly agree. But for this particular purpose (soft delete) where you want to handle it uniformly application-wide it should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`@Filter`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-filters) or [`@Where`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-entity) Annotation.

As far as I know this is the usual way to restrict collection fetching.